# Check if value exists in selectpicker options

Tags: javascript, select, bootstrap-selectpicker

I need to check if an option(arrayItem) already exists in my selectpicker to populate it with :

```
$("#iselectroledirregional").append('<option value="' + arrayItem + '">' + arrayItem + '</option>').selectpicker('refresh');
```

I already tried this in an if/else statement:

```
$("#yourSelect option[value='yourValue']").length > 0;
```

But it doesn't work because my select dropdown does no contains a value tag :

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can set a specific class on each label span like this:

```
<span class=text val-NR">NR<span>
```

Then you have the possibility to check it with this code:

```
$("#yourSelect a[role='option'] > span.val-NR").length > 0;
```

Another way is to use the jquery contains pseudo class:

```
$("#yourSelect a[role='option'] > span:contains('NR')").length > 0;
```

You can find the contains selector here: https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/.  If this not works fine, then give us the full html and js code.

Comment: I cannot use the first one but your third seems to be good, I tried it but I never have a true on this condition

Comment: try to make the selector more short:  $("#yourSelect 
 span:contains('NR')").length > 0;

Comment: You can also try to execute this code in the developer web console of your browser:   $("#yourSelect span:contains('NR')").length

Comment: I always get false

Comment: Here is how my HTML is rendered. I can't even see my two options in the dropdown http://jsfiddle.net/decodeman/v7naao59/